# How to generate PDF having HTML like capabilities using Java

Tags: java, itext, dynamicpdf

I need to create PDF using some java API which has the capabilities like HTML. Basically, I want to create a form which can take input from users, perform some basic client side validations and also generate this PDF programmatically using Java. I am also looking for rich HTML like features like expand, collapse, hyperlinks, add a section on a button click etc. So basically I am trying to create an HTML like page but within PDF.

I have tried using itext but able to only to do only handful of things and not able to add dynamism into PDF. Is there any tool/API which supports this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PDF itself allows you to embed (a subset of) javascript.

This embedded code can be linked to document events (e.g. opening the document) or specific form elements (e.g. clicking a button, changing the text in a text-input field).

This is a page from their website entitled '[Making a PDF interactive](https://itextpdf.com/en/resources/books/itext-7-jump-start-tutorial-java/chapter-4-making-pdf-interactive)' which focusses on adding form elements.

The book ([iText in Action](https://itextpdf.com/sites/default/files/attachments/PR%20-%20iText%20in%20Action%20-%20Second%20edition%20e-book.pdf)) by Bruno Lowagie (original founder of iText) also goes in great detail. It even shows how to program a calculator in a PDF document, page 232.

I'm just going to copy-paste the relevant section here.

**Listing 7.29 Calculator**

```
public void addTextField(PdfWriter writer, Rectangle rect, String name) {
    PdfFormField field = PdfFormField.createTextField(writer, false, false, 0);
     field.setFieldName(name);
     field.setWidget(rect, PdfAnnotation.HIGHLIGHT_NONE);
     field.setQuadding(PdfFormField.Q_RIGHT);
     field.setFieldFlags(PdfFormField.FF_READ_ONLY);
     writer.addAnnotation(field);
}    

public void addPushButton(PdfWriter writer, Rectangle rect, String btn, String script) {
    float w = rect.getWidth();
    float h = rect.getHeight();
    PdfFormField pushbutton = PdfFormField.createPushButton(writer);
    pushbutton.setFieldName("btn_" + btn);
    pushbutton.setWidget(rect, PdfAnnotation.HIGHLIGHT_PUSH);
    PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent();
    pushbutton.setAppearance(PdfAnnotation.APPEARANCE_NORMAL, createAppearance(cb, btn, BaseColor.GRAY, w, h));
    pushbutton.setAppearance(PdfAnnotation.APPEARANCE_ROLLOVER, createAppearance(cb, btn, BaseColor.RED, w, h));
    pushbutton.setAppearance(PdfAnnotation.APPEARANCE_DOWN, createAppearance(cb, btn, BaseColor.BLUE, w, h));
    pushbutton.setAdditionalActions(PdfName.U, PdfAction.javaScript(script, writer));
    pushbutton.setAdditionalActions(PdfName.E, PdfAction.javaScript( "this.showMove('" + btn + "');", writer));
    pushbutton.setAdditionalActions(PdfName.X, PdfAction.javaScript( "this.showMove(' ');", writer));
    writer.addAnnotation(pushbutton);
}

public PdfAppearance createAppearance(PdfContentByte cb, String btn, BaseColor color, float w, float h) {
    PdfAppearance app = cb.createAppearance(w, h);
    app.setColorFill(color);
    app.rectangle(2, 2, w - 4, h - 4);
    app.fill();
    app.beginText();
    app.setColorFill(BaseColor.BLACK);
    app.setFontAndSize(bf, h / 2);
    app.showTextAligned(Element.ALIGN_CENTER, btn, w / 2, h / 4, 0);
    app.endText();
    return app;
}
```

Comment: I am able to generate the PDF and put some validations but I am not able to understand if on click of a button we can add a text box dynamically?  Is it possible to embed add java snippet within JavaScript which can add a text box or any other widget?

Comment: You can definitely set text of a textbox from the inner javascript. For the specific details of what you can do with the javascript subset, I think it's best to check out the PDF reference.